# How can I move to a different Page using onClick props of Material UI table action in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, action, render, material-table

> Here in Material UI table I use an Action to watch details of my data,
> So I want to move a page or render a new component whenever I click on this action button.
> Please help me to  do this efficiently. Thanks in advance.
>
> [ I tried to do this using history.push() but it giving error : unexpected use of history ]
>
> ```
> import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
> import { get, getDatabase, orderByKey, query, ref } from "firebase/database";
> import MaterialTable from "material-table";
> import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
> import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
> import GridLoader from "react-spinners/GridLoader";
> import useVideos from "../hooks/useVideos";
> import { useHistory } from "react-router";
>
> const initialState = [{}];
> const reducer = (state, action) => {
>   switch (action.type) {
>     case "videos":
>       const data = [];
>       let cnt = 1;
>       action.value.forEach((video, index) => {
>         data.push({
>           sl: cnt,
>           noq: video.noq,
>           id: index,
>           youtubeID: video.youtubeID,
>           title: video.title,
>         });
>         cnt = cnt + 1;
>       });
>       return data;
>     default:
>       return state;
>   }
> };
>
> export default function ManageVideos() {
>   const { addVideo, updateVideo, deleteVideo } = useVideos("");
>   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
>   const [error, setError] = useState(false);
>   const [cnt, setCnt] = useState(0);
>   const [videoList, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
>   const history = useHistory();
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     async function fetchVideos() {
>       const db = getDatabase();
>       const videosRef = ref(db, "videos");
>       const videoQuery = query(videosRef, orderByKey());
>       try {
>         setError(false);
>         setLoading(true);
>         const snapShot = await get(videoQuery);
>         setLoading(false);
>         if (snapShot.exists()) {
>           dispatch({
>             type: "videos",
>             value: snapShot.val(),
>           });
>         }
>       } catch (err) {
>         console.log(err);
>         setLoading(false);
>         setError(true);
>       }
>     }
>     fetchVideos();
>   }, [cnt]);
>
>   const columns = [
>     { title: "Serial", field: "sl", editable: "never" },
>     {
>       title: "Title",
>       field: "title",
>       validate: (rowData) => rowData.title !== "",
>     },
>     {
>       title: "Number of Qusetion",
>       field: "noq",
>       editable: "never",
>     },
>     {
>       title: "Youtube Video Id",
>       field: "youtubeID",
>       validate: (rowData) => rowData.youtubeID !== "",
>     },
>   ];
>   return (
>     <div>
>         <MaterialTable
>           title="Videos Table"
>           data={videoList}
>           columns={columns}
>           options={{
>             export: true,
>             grouping: true,
>             filtering: true,
>           }}
>           editable={{
>             onRowAdd: (newData) =>
>               new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>                 setTimeout(() => {
>                   addVideo(newData);
>                   setCnt((prevCnt) => prevCnt + 1);
>                   resolve();
>                 }, 1000);
>               }),
>           }}
>           actions={[
>             {
>               icon: "add_box",
>               color: "info",
>               tooltip: "View Video Details",
>               onClick: () => {
>
>                 history.push("/addQuiz");
>                // want to write something to move a new page or render a component.
>               
>
>               },
>             },
>           ]}
>         />
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> ```

Comment: Solved ! unfortunately i import the useHistory form 'react-router' that's why i got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function looks like perfect! For navigation, you need to add route in router file. And specify component you want to render on that route.

For redirection from component, you can do something like this.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
const history = useHistory();


history.push('/dahsboard'/) // your route url
```

Comment: I tried to do this using history.push() but it giving error : Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: @Md.JoynalAlam have you tried "window.location.href="/dashboard" ?

Comment: Can you share your latest code with useHistory?

Comment: @Chemi Adel - Thanks ! `window.location.href="/dashboard"` it works!

Comment: @Md.JoynalAlam You are welcome, but he still right about what he says, window.location will make new request to the browser. so isn't the best solution

Comment: @MaulikShah I update the code with useHistory(), Please check it!